# What is the difference between http-equiv="author" and name="author"?

Tags: html, meta

Hello I'm learning HTML5 and I'm wondering what is the difference between these two meta elements ?

```
<meta http-equiv="author" content="Jon Smith" />
<meta name="author" content="Jon Smith" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is not valid, `http-equiv` is enumerated, i.e. it has a set of values that are valid for it and `author` is not one. (Its intended as a way to pass pragma data to the browser such as rendering instructions, not *meta* data like document properties.)

`<meta name="author" content="Jon Smith" />` is valid.

Comment: Can you expand with examples please *(typical `http-equiv` as against `name`)*?

Comment: The possible values for *http-equiv* are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-http-equiv

Comment: The *name="whatever"* semantics are described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-name